# identity for squared binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I was wondering if there is an identity for squaring a binomial coefficient.
I know there is one with converting it to a linear equation, but I am looking to stay at a "coefficient" level. something like:

$${n \choose k}^2={n \choose K}$$

where K is a function of k. Did not find anything like it, sorry if this is a re-post.
Thanks

Comment: @leonbloy thanks for the edit!

Comment: You're welcome - and welcome to MSE. Remember that latex code must be enclosed in dollar signs.

Comment: The trivial case $k=K=0, k=K=n$ works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take $n=2k>0$ there is no $K$ satisfying the equation:
$${n \choose k}^2={n \choose K}$$
because ${n \choose k}$ is maximum when $k=n/2$.

So, in general, your equation cannot be satisfied.